# Cómo alinear un banner fuera de la caja de contenido

Tags: wordpress

estoy usando Wordpress con el theme MH Magazine Lite y quiero poner un banner de adsense fuera de la caja de contenido.

Lo he puesto, pero cuando la pantalla es más chica de los 1440, el banner se sobrepone en el contenido, como puedo hacer para que el banner siempre se encuentre al lado de la caja de contenido y no se sobre ponga? lo puse en una position fixed, para que el banner baje con el contenido, pero no encuentro como hacerlo que no se sobreponga.

Answer (score 0):

Sin ver nada de código es muy difícil decir.
Prueba con este estilo:

```
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float:left; //o right según los gustos
```